# redirect another action with params in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I post to delete action in below:

```
public function deletenews($newsid)
    {
        $news = News::where('id',$newsid)->first();//find($comment_id)
        $message = 'a string';
        $msgstatus = 'another string';
        ...
        return redirect()->route('usernews',[$message,$msgstatus]);
    }
```

I want to direct to this action with parameters:

```
public function usernews($message=null,$msgstatus=null)
    {
        ...
        return view('usercontrol.usernews',compact(['news','msgstatus','message']));
    }
```

it redirects and works fine but somehow parameters always null, I will use this parameters to inform user that record deleted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function deletenews($newsid)
{
    $news = News::where('id',$newsid)->first();//find($comment_id)
    $message = 'a string';
    $msgstatus = 'another string';
    ...
    return redirect()->route('usernews' ['message'=>$message,'msgstatus'=>$msgstatus]);
}

public function usernews(Request $request)
{
    $message = $request->input('message');
    $msgstatus = $request->input('msgstatus');
    ...
    return view('usercontrol.usernews',compact(['news','msgstatus','message']));
}
```

Comment: actually its not I want, this way url "deletenews/id" not change in browser so when client click next page in table this posts to deletenews action again.. which main issue here but ok.